# Strange behaviour while multiplying negative number with -1

Tags: linux, bash

Iam doing scripting using bash where I get the negative number like this

> -001 , -002 , -003 , ........................., -008 , -009 , -010 , -011 , -012 .....

I have to change them to positive number so I decided to multiply -1 with them.
Then

```
$ val=$(( -1*-001 ))
$ echo $val
$ 1
$ val=$(( -1*-002 ))
$ echo $val
$ 2
```

Result are fine up to number -007 but when I multiply with -008 and -009 then error occur as below

```
$ val=$(( -1*-008 ))
bash: -1*-008: value too great for base (error token is "008")

$ val=$(( -1*-009 ))
bash: -1*-009: value too great for base (error token is "009")
```

Another strange behaviour is that when I multiply with -010, -011 ,-012 and so on... unusual result occur like below

```
$ val=$(( -1*-010 ))
$ echo $val
$ 8
$ val=$(( -1*-011 ))
$ echo $val
$ 9
$ val=$(( -1*-012 ))
$ echo $val
$ 10
$ val=$(( -1*-013 ))
$ echo $val
$ 11

and so on............
```

Why this happens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Leading zeros denote numbers in octal. 010 and 10 are not the same number; the first is octal: 010 octal is 8 in decimal. Similarly, "009" isn't a real number, hence the error you're seeing: there *is no digit* "9" in octal.

You need to strip leading zeros.

Comment: Thanks I got answer. What is simple method to strip leading zeros.can you help.

Comment: You should avoid entering the leading zeros in the first place. If you want to know how to strip them, [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/ask).

Answer (score 6):

You can force decimal (instead of octal) values with 10# prefix :

```
$ val=$(( -1*-10#008 ))
$ echo $val
8
```